# Import Error when running Tensorflow

Tags: python, cuda, tensorflow, virtualenv, cudnn

I've been trying to set up GPU enabled Tensorflow for a while and I'm stuck at this point. when I try to import tensorflow into my program I get the following error:

ImportError: libcudnn.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I've checked /usr/local/cuda/lib64/ and sure enough libcudnn.so.5 is there and it is readable by anyone so that should be fine. I'm installing Tensorflow using virtualenv so I thought perhaps it was looking for it somewhere else but I can't figure out where else it would look for the file. Anyone have any idea of what the problem could be?

Comment: is `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, or otherwise visible to the runtime dynamic linker?  Including in the environment that tf is running in?  It would likely be helpful/useful if you posted all output up to the point of the import error.

Comment: Yep, LD_LIBRARY_PATH seems to have been the problem, I had installed ROS recently and it seems to have set that variable to point to a different location. Changing the variable to /usr/local/cuda/lib64 seems to have solved it for me, thanks! If you'd like post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer!

Comment: You can have multiple locations specified in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.  Each path in it (separated by `:`) is a path the runtime linker will search when it is looking for libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!